# Can I substitute sqlite for native php functionality without an unacceptable performance hit?

Tags: php, database, sqlite

In php I am retrieving 2 sets of data from subsequent API calls returning around 100 records each.

One set represents parent objects the other none, one or two child objects matching up with a record in the parent set based on a shared key value.

I had planned to store the values in an object and those records in an array which I could then loop through and filter as needed. But perhaps that's overkill. Once the page runs it will cache for around two hours.

Could I just clear two sqlite tables each time the page retrieves data, insert them, and then run a query instead of doing the process with objects and arrays?

I am willing to accept an extra 2 seconds of overhead for added simplicity. Is sqlite able to perform 100 inserts in each of two tables and a select query with a join in that amount of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just try it? Two seconds on your given hardware is liable to be different to two seconds on mine, so if this is a meaningful constraint, then you need to actually implement and measure how long it takes.

i.e.: Don't estimate what you can measure.

However, as a completely off the cuff guesstimate (that I won't stand behind and will in fact repudiate in a casual, perhaps slightly mocking manner whilst shaking my head in the manner of a disappointed uncle), I'd be surprised if it took SQLite two seconds to carry out what you're trying to do.

Comment: +1 for sensible answer. In addition, for best performance, one should remember to wrap the entire operation within a single SQLite BEGIN / END TRANSACTION.  That way, you are performing one disk flush at the end of the transaction (fast) rather than many flushes, one for each individual INSERT (slow).

Comment: Eric thanks for the comment about utilizing the Begin/End Transaction

Answer (score 0):

Provided you use a transaction, SQLite can do thousands of inserts in a second so it should cope with a hundred or so easily. Using a transaction is the key, if you don't it'll create a transaction automatically for each insert individually which slows things way down. Querying with a join is not really its strongest point, but if your query structure isn't overly complex I'd imagine it could do it all inside the two seconds.

That's just a guess though, in reality it all depends though on your exact database schema, data and hardware. The only way to really know is to try it and see.